# How to format a phone number with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently displaying phone numbers like `2124771000`. However, I need the number to be formatted in a more human-readable form, for example: `212-477-1000`. Here's my current `HTML`:

```
<p class="phone">2124771000</p>
```

Comment: Too Late answer  , but just for help those who landing on this page

URL : http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

Comment: Not sure that I understand the closed status on this one. Not Constructive doesn't seem right... I find this information extremely useful and a direct association to the issue that brought me here. I do not contest the fact that it is closed, but the displayed reason for being closed

Comment: Perhaps the question got edited and was less descriptive before...it seems like a perfectly valid SO question and answer to me, and lots of upvotes.

Comment: Googles library https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber no jQuery required.

Answer (score 223, accepted):

Simple: http://jsfiddle.net/Xxk3F/3/

```
$('.phone').text(function(i, text) {
    return text.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, '$1-$2-$3');
});
```

Or: http://jsfiddle.net/Xxk3F/1/

```
$('.phone').text(function(i, text) {
    return text.replace(/(\d\d\d)(\d\d\d)(\d\d\d\d)/, '$1-$2-$3');
});
```

Note: The .text() method cannot be used on input elements. For input field text, use the .val() method.

Comment: I've modified this to support 'change' events within input fields. http://jsfiddle.net/gUsUK/

Comment: A bit more robust of a regex (though it requires a custom replace function) would be `/(\d{3})?(\d{3})(\d{4})$/` in case there is no area code

Comment: Is it valid for phone numbers all over the world?

Comment: If you have multiple phone numbers on the page consider using the $(selector).each() function to easily apply this mask to all numbers.

Comment: I want to implement it with keypress and blur event. It's not formatting phone number when digits are less than 10.
Sample code is:

`$('#x_phone').on('keypress blur',function() {
  var ph = $(this).val();
  
  var temp = ph.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, '$1-$2-$3');
  $(this).val(temp);
  //alert(temp);
 });`

Comment: this is working well in windows environment but not working in iOS device. is there any alternative that works in both platform

Answer (score 55):

```
var phone = '2124771000',
    formatted = phone.substr(0, 3) + '-' + phone.substr(3, 3) + '-' + phone.substr(6,4)
```

Comment: @AndreasAL: Because a regex engine has heavy overhead, especially for something where the input format is known and simple string operations are FAR more efficient. And of course, there's the rule that using a regex for a problem just makes you have two problems.

Comment: This solution also properly formats phone numbers with letters in them, like "212555IDEA".

Answer (score 14):

Don't forget to ensure you are working with purely integers.

```
var separator = '-';
$( ".phone" ).text( function( i, DATA ) {
    DATA
        .replace( /[^\d]/g, '' )
        .replace( /(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, '$1' + separator + '$2' + separator + '$3' );
    return DATA;
});
```

Answer (score 12):

Here's a combination of some of these answers. This can be used for input fields. Deals with phone numbers that are 7 and 10 digits long.

```
// Used to format phone number
function phoneFormatter() {
  $('.phone').on('input', function() {
    var number = $(this).val().replace(/[^\d]/g, '')
    if (number.length == 7) {
      number = number.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "$1-$2");
    } else if (number.length == 10) {
      number = number.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "($1) $2-$3");
    }
    $(this).val(number)
  });
}
```

Live example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cruznunez/a4jbqqsv/)

I know this doesn't directly answer the question, but when I was looking up answers this was one of the first pages I found. So this answer is for anyone searching for something similar to what I was searching for.

Answer (score 7):

Use a library to handle phone number. [Libphonenumber](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber) by Google is your best bet.

```
// Require `PhoneNumberFormat`.
var PNF = require('google-libphonenumber').PhoneNumberFormat;

// Get an instance of `PhoneNumberUtil`.
var phoneUtil = require('google-libphonenumber').PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();

// Parse number with country code.
var phoneNumber = phoneUtil.parse('202-456-1414', 'US');

// Print number in the international format.
console.log(phoneUtil.format(phoneNumber, PNF.INTERNATIONAL));
// => +1 202-456-1414
```

I recommend to use this [package](https://github.com/seegno/google-libphonenumber) by seegno.

Answer (score 4):

try something like this..

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("phoneValidate", function(number, element) {
    number = number.replace(/\s+/g, ""); 
    return this.optional(element) || number.length > 9 &&
        number.match(/^(1-?)?(\([2-9]\d{2}\)|[2-9]\d{2})-?[2-9]\d{2}-?\d{4}$/);
}, "Please specify a valid phone number");

$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: true,
      phoneValidate: true
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I have provided jsfiddle link for you to format US phone numbers as 
(XXX) XXX-XXX

```
 $('.class-name').on('keypress', function(e) {
  var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode || 0;
  var phone = $(this);
  if (phone.val().length === 0) {
    phone.val(phone.val() + '(');
  }
  // Auto-format- do not expose the mask as the user begins to type
  if (key !== 8 && key !== 9) {
    if (phone.val().length === 4) {
      phone.val(phone.val() + ')');
    }
    if (phone.val().length === 5) {
      phone.val(phone.val() + ' ');
    }
    if (phone.val().length === 9) {
      phone.val(phone.val() + '-');
    }
    if (phone.val().length >= 14) {
      phone.val(phone.val().slice(0, 13));
    }
  }

  // Allow numeric (and tab, backspace, delete) keys only
  return (key == 8 ||
    key == 9 ||
    key == 46 ||
    (key >= 48 && key <= 57) ||
    (key >= 96 && key <= 105));
})

.on('focus', function() {
  phone = $(this);

  if (phone.val().length === 0) {
    phone.val('(');
  } else {
    var val = phone.val();
    phone.val('').val(val); // Ensure cursor remains at the end
  }
})

.on('blur', function() {
  $phone = $(this);

  if ($phone.val() === '(') {
    $phone.val('');
  }
});
```

Live example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kapilrc/rz3w34ue/1/)

Comment: How can I change this pattern to show number from left to right like ==> (021)88888888

Answer (score 4):

#### Quick roll your own code:

Here is a solution modified from [Cruz Nunez's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37555997/5411817) above.

```
// Used to format phone number
function phoneFormatter() {
  $('.phone').on('input', function() {
    var number = $(this).val().replace(/[^\d]/g, '')
    if (number.length < 7) {
      number = number.replace(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})/, "($1) $2");
    } else if (number.length <= 10) {
    number = number.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{1,4})/, "($1) $2-$3");
    } else {
    // ignore additional digits
    number = number.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{1,3})(\d{1,4})(\d.*)/, "($1) $2-$3");
    }
    $(this).val(number)
  });
};

$(phoneFormatter);
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SherylHohman/x2edr1cv/10/)

- In this solution, the formatting is applied no matter how many digits the user has entered.  (In Nunes' solution, the formatting is applied only when exactly 7 or 10 digits has been entered.)
- It requires the zip code for a 10-digit US phone number to be entered.
- Both solutions, however, editing already entered digits is problematic, as typed digits always get added to the end.
- I recommend, instead, the robust jQuery Mask Plugin code, mentioned below:

#### Recommend jQuery Mask Plugin

I recommend using [jQuery Mask Plugin](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/) (page has live examples), [on github](https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin).
These links have minimal explanations on how to use:

- https://dobsondev.com/2017/04/14/using-jquery-mask-to-mask-form-input/
- http://www.igorescobar.com/blog/2012/05/06/masks-with-jquery-mask-plugin/
- http://www.igorescobar.com/blog/2013/04/30/using-jquery-mask-plugin-with-zepto-js/

**CDN**
Instead of installing/hosting the code, you can also add a link to a CDN of the script
[CDN Link for jQuery Mask Plugin](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery.mask)
`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.16/jquery.mask.min.js" integrity="sha512-pHVGpX7F/27yZ0ISY+VVjyULApbDlD0/X0rgGbTqCE7WFW5MezNTWG/dnhtbBuICzsd0WQPgpE4REBLv+UqChw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

or
`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.16/jquery.mask.js" integrity="sha512-pHVGpX7F/27yZ0ISY+VVjyULApbDlD0/X0rgGbTqCE7WFW5MezNTWG/dnhtbBuICzsd0WQPgpE4REBLv+UqChw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

#### WordPress Contact Form 7: use Masks Form Fields plugin

If you are using Contact Form 7 plugin on a WordPress site, the easiest option to control form fields is if you can simply add a class to your input field to take care of it for you.
[Masks Form Fields plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/masks-form-fields/) is *one* option that makes this easy to do.
I like this option, as, Internally, it embeds a minimized version of the code from [jQuery Mask Plugin](https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin) mentioned above.

Example usage on a Contact Form 7 form:

```
<label> Your Phone Number (required)
    [tel* customer-phone class:phone_us minlength:14 placeholder "(555) 555-5555"]
</label>
```

The important part here is `class:phone_us`.
Note that if you use `minlength`/`maxlength`, the length must include the mask characters, in addition to the digits.

Comment: one problem with this is that, you can't delete the first three numbers :(

Comment: If you don't want area code, try something like: `minlength:8 placeholder "555-5555"`? I haven't had to adjust my code for a while and do not recall specifics on how to edit the library, or the templates offhand. You could ignore the area code you get back, but how to make it invisible to the user, or fill it with characters the user cannot edit (or see), I'm not sure offhand. I did make a custom version of the library once to make a custom field. I found it not difficult to modify. Then I realized the mods weren't even needed. If templates won't work, maybe try taking a peek at their code?

Answer (score 2):

Consider libphonenumber-js (https://github.com/halt-hammerzeit/libphonenumber-js) which is a smaller version of the full and famous libphonenumber.

Quick and dirty example:

```
$(".phone-format").keyup(function() {
// Don't reformat backspace/delete so correcting mistakes is easier
if (event.keyCode != 46 && event.keyCode != 8) {
    var val_old = $(this).val();
    var newString = new libphonenumber.asYouType('US').input(val_old);
    $(this).focus().val('').val(newString);
}
});
```

(If you do use a regex to avoid a library download, avoid reformat on backspace/delete will make it easier to correct typos.)

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```js
function formatPhoneNumber(value, pattern) {
  let i = 0,
    phone = value.toString();
  return pattern.replace(/#/g, _ => phone[i++]);
}

console.log(formatPhoneNumber('2124771000', '###-###-####'));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 $(".phoneString").text(function(i, text) {
            text = text.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "($1) $2-$3");
            return text;
        });
```

Output :-(123) 657-8963

Answer (score 1):

I found this question while googling for a way to auto-format phone numbers via a jQuery plugin. The accepted answer was not ideal for my needs and a lot has happened in the 6 years since it was originally posted. I eventually found the solution and am documenting it here for posterity.

**Problem**

I would like my phone number html input field to auto-format (mask) the value as the user types.

**Solution**

Check out [Cleave.js](https://nosir.github.io/cleave.js/). It is a very powerful/flexible and easy way to solve this problem, and many other data masking issues.

Formatting a phone number is as easy as:

```
var cleave = new Cleave('.input-element', {
    phone: true,
    phoneRegionCode: 'US'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Input:**

```
4546644645
```

**Code:**

```
PhoneNumber = Input.replace(/(\d\d\d)(\d\d\d)(\d\d\d\d)/, "($1)$2-$3");
```

**OutPut:**

```
(454)664-4645
```

Answer (score 0):

Following event handler should do the needful:

```
$('[name=mobilePhone]').on('keyup', function(e){
                    var enteredNumberStr=this.$('[name=mobilePhone]').val(),                    
                      //Filter only numbers from the input
                      cleanedStr = (enteredNumberStr).replace(/\D/g, ''),
                      inputLength=cleanedStr.length,
                      formattedNumber=cleanedStr;                     
                                      
                      if(inputLength>3 && inputLength<7) {
                        formattedNumber= cleanedStr.substr(0,3) + '-' + cleanedStr.substr(3,inputLength-1) ;
                      }else if (inputLength>=7 && inputLength<10) {
                          formattedNumber= cleanedStr.substr(0,3) + '-' + cleanedStr.substr(3,3) + '-' + cleanedStr.substr(6,inputLength-1);                          
                      }else if(inputLength>=10) {
                          formattedNumber= cleanedStr.substr(0,3) + '-' + cleanedStr.substr(3,3) + '-' + cleanedStr.substr(6,inputLength-1);                        
                      }
                      console.log(formattedNumber);
                      this.$('[name=mobilePhone]').val(formattedNumber);
            });
```

Answer (score -1):

To expand on Cruz Nunez code and add continual formatting, plus include some international phone number formats.

```
    $('#phone').on('input', function() {
      var number = $(this).val().replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
      if (number.length == 3) {
        number = number.replace(/(\d{3})/, "$1-");
      } else if (number.length == 4) {
        number = number.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{1})/, "$1-$2");
      } else if (number.length == 5) {
        number = number.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{2})/, "$1-$2");
      } else if (number.length == 6) {
        number = number.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})/, "$1-$2-");
      } else if (number.length == 7) {
        number = number.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{1})/, "$1-$2-$3");
      } else if (number.length == 8) {
        number = number.replace(/(\d{4})(\d{4})/, "$1-$2");
      } else if (number.length == 9) {
        number = number.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})/, "$1-$2-$3");
      } else if (number.length == 10) {
        number = number.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "$1-$2-$3");
      } else if (number.length == 11) {
        number = number.replace(/(\d{1})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "$1-$2-$3-$4");
      } else if (number.length == 12) {
        number = number.replace(/(\d{2})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "$1-$2-$3-$4");
      }
      $(this).val(number);
    });
```

Answer (score -3):

may be this will help

```
var countryCode = +91;
var phone=1234567890;
phone=phone.split('').reverse().join('');//0987654321
var formatPhone=phone.substring(0,4)+'-';//0987-
phone=phone.replace(phone.substring(0,4),'');//654321
while(phone.length>0){
formatPhone=formatPhone+phone.substring(0,3)+'-';
phone=phone.replace(phone.substring(0,3),'');
}
formatPhone=countryCode+formatPhone.split('').reverse().join('');
```

you will get +91-123-456-7890