# Auto Format Phone Number in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one textbox for phone number. My phone number should be XXX-XXX-XXX like this format.

I got the solution for XXX-XXX-XXX format, but i don't know how to modify that code.

```
$('#ssn').keyup(function() {
    var val = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
    var newVal = '';
    while (val.length > 3) {
      newVal += val.substr(0, 3) + '-';
      val = val.substr(3);
    }
    newVal += val;
    this.value = newVal;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ssthil/nY2QT/

Comment: didn't get how you want the final format to be?

Comment: what's the difference between format of your solution and the format you want?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a phone number with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760070/how-to-format-a-phone-number-with-jquery)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery you can try jquery [masked-input-plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/).

There's a jsFiddle for you [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vandalo/7Q6gx/) where you can see how it works.

The source code for the project on GitHub can be found [here](https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput).

The implementation is more than simple:

HTML:

```
<input id="ssn"/>
```

javascript:

```
$("#ssn").mask("999-999-999");
```

**UPDATE**:

Another good one can be found [here](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/).

Comment: Thanks for your solution. But I want to do through customized jquery code rather than plugin. I'm still beigginer in jQuery..

Comment: @Sivasenthil: I can understand that. Probably the best is have a look at that code and try to create your own version.

Answer (score 7):

As far as I can work out, all you really need to do is this:

```
$('#ssn').keyup(function()
{
    this.value = this.value.replace(/(\d{3})\-?/g,'$1-');
});
```

but this will only work when people enter digits, so I'd suggest an introducing an extra check:

```js
$('#ssn').keyup(function(e) {
  if ((e.keyCode > 47 && e.keyCode < 58) || (e.keyCode < 106 && e.keyCode > 95)) {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/(\d{3})\-?/g, '$1-');
    return true;
  }
  
  //remove all chars, except dash and digits
  this.value = this.value.replace(/[^\-0-9]/g, '');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="ssn">
```

A little more on the regex `/(\d{3})\-?/g`: 
 This replaces group of 3 digits with itself, followed by a dash. The brackets create a back reference to the matched digits, that is used in the replacement string (`$1-` -> $1 being the back reference).
Note that an optional dash is replaced, too, but not included in the back reference. if the input is `123`, and the replace pattern would be something like `/(\d{3})/g`, or `/(\d{3}\-?)/g` the value would become `123-4`, `123--45`, `123---456` and so on, doubling the dashes each time.

*Warning*:
This will give the user some grief, since the arrow keys and such won't work.Luckily, that's an easy fix: Just add the following code at the top of your function:

```
if (e.keyCode > 36 && e.keyCode < 41)
{
    return true;
}
```

And the arrows work just fine. for other keys (such as delete, backspace, shift etc...) [check this page](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes).

For a full example: [here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/caxkm/)

Comment: your solution **doubles** the dashes even when user only enters digits.
I am talking about this one - `this.value = this.value.replace(/(\d{3})/g,'$1-');`

Comment: I've corrected the first snippet. The actual solution I suggested (the fiddle I set up), however, doesn't double the dashes.

Comment: This is a really good solution, how could I take this code and edit it to allow a phone number mask such as xxx-xxx-xxxx?

Answer (score 2):

For the formatting XXX-XXX-XXXX here is a simple solution:

```
if(this.value.trim().length <= 8){
    this.value = this.value.replace(/(\d{3})\-?/g,'$1-');
 }
```

Here is an example and you not need any framework or library or npm:

```
this.phone.addEventListener('keyup', event => {

        if(this.phone.value.trim().length <= 8){
            this.phone.value = this.phone.value.replace(/(\d{3})\-?/g,'$1-');
        }
    }
```

You could also do this if you like:

```
 this.phone.addEventListener('keyup', event => {

        if(this.phone.value.trim().length <= 8){
            this.phone.value = this.phone.value.replace(/(\d{3})\-?/g,'$1-');
        }else{
            this.phone.value = this.phone.value.replace(/(\d{4})\-?/g,'$1');
        }
    }
```

Replace this `this.phone` with your value.
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found this question while googling for a way to auto-format phone numbers in Javascript. The accepted answer was not ideal for my needs and a lot has happened in the 6 years since it was originally posted. I eventually found the solution and am documenting it here for posterity.

**Problem**

I would like my phone number html input field to auto-format (mask) the value as the user types.

**Solution**

Check out [Cleave.js](https://nosir.github.io/cleave.js/). It is a very powerful/flexible and easy way to solve this problem, and many other data masking issues.

Formatting a phone number is as easy as:

```
var cleave = new Cleave('.input-element', {
    phone: true,
    phoneRegionCode: 'US'
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
$('#ssn').keyup(function() {
        var val = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
        var newVal = '';
        for(i=0;i<2;i++){
         if (val.length > 3) {
          newVal += val.substr(0, 3) + '-';
          val = val.substr(3);
        }
        }
        newVal += val;
        this.value = newVal;
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="ssn" maxlength="10"/>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can set input mask on any field in 3 simple steps:

1: First of all call these libraries 
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"
"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/jquery.maskedinput.js"

2: Create simple form like this :

```
<form> <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" /> </form>
```

3: Then the script code past into your script tag..

$(document).ready(function($) {

```
$('#phone').mask("99999-9999999-9",{placeholder:""});
```

});