# jQuery or Javascript to autoformat phone mask

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Rails app that I'm recording a `text_field` as a `string` which is a phone number that I'd like auto-formatted in the following mask `xxx-xxx-xxxx`

I was searching Stack Overflow and found this [auto-format-phone-number-in-jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930866/auto-format-phone-number-in-jquery-can-anyone-help-me-please) but the OP was looking to format a mask of `xxx-xxx-xxx` and I need to figure out how to do a mask of `xxx-xxx-xxxx`

I've borrowed a snipped from this answer and it does work but again formats as `xxx-xxx-xxxx`

```
$(function(){
  $('#call_caller_phone').keyup(function()
  {
     this.value = this.value.replace(/(\d{3})\-?/g,'$1-');
  });
});
```

Can anyone assist me with formatting in the `xxx-xxx-xxxx` mask?

Comment: Since you're using JQuery, why not go with http://plugins.jquery.com/mask/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I written custom jQuery code , Please check below code snippet

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#yourphone").bind('paste', function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        var inputValue = e.originalEvent && e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('Text');
        inputValue = inputValue.replace(/\D/g, '');
        if (!$.isNumeric(inputValue)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            if (inputValue.length > 9) {
                inputValue = String(inputValue.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "$1-$2-$3"));
            } else {
                inputValue = String(inputValue.replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, '$1-'));
            }
            $(this).val(inputValue);
            $(this).val('');
            inputValue = inputValue.substring(0, 12);
            $(this).val(inputValue);
        }
    });



    $("#yourphone").on('keydown touchend', function (e) {

        e = e || window.event;
        var key = e.which || e.keyCode; // keyCode detection
        var ctrl = e.ctrlKey ? e.ctrlKey : ((key === 17) ? true : false); // ctrl detection
        if (key == 86 && ctrl) { // Ctrl + V Pressed !

        } else if (key == 67 && ctrl) { // Ctrl + C Pressed !

        } else if (key == 88 && ctrl) { // Ctrl + x Pressed !

        } else if (key == 65 && ctrl) { // Ctrl + a Pressed !
            $(this).trigger("paste");
        } else if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && !(e.keyCode >= 96 && e.keyCode <= 105) && !(e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 57)) {
            return false;
        }
        var curchr = this.value.length;
        var curval = $(this).val();
        if (curchr == 3 && e.which != 8 && e.which != 0) {
            $(this).val(curval + "-");
        } else if (curchr == 7 && e.which != 8 && e.which != 0) {
            $(this).val(curval + "-");
        }
        $(this).attr('maxlength', '12');
    });

});
```

Working fiddle Example http://jsfiddle.net/rajaramtt/7s3eLokc/22/

Edit:
I have developed jquery-input-mask-phone-number plugin, simply include CDN to your HTML file and call the usPhoneFormat method.

$(document).ready(function () {
$('#yourphone').usPhoneFormat();
});

Working JSFiddle Link https://jsfiddle.net/rajaramtt/orpehtxc/1/

NPM Reference URL https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-input-mask-phone-number

GitHub Reference URL https://github.com/rajaramtt/jquery-input-mask-phone-number

Comment: This is much simpler and fits the use case better.  Thank for contributing!

Comment: @nulltek  Thanks, Happy Coding!

Answer (score 5):

I believe this might work.

```js
$(function(){
  $('#call_caller_phone').keyup(function()
  {
     this.value = this.value.replace(/(\d{3})\-?(\d{3})\-?(\d{4})/,'$1-$2-$3');
    //alert ("OK");
  });
});
```

```css
#call_caller_phone {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="call_caller_phone" type="text">
```

Comment: Why should this work? Your believe isn't enough to convince me. Explain why!

Comment: _Why?_  This **(\d{3})\-?** takes three digits followed by an optional dash and stores it in **$1**.  The next **(\d{3})\-?** takes the next three digits followed by an optional dash and stores it in **$2**.  The final **(\d{4})** takes the next four digits and stores it in $3.  This part **'$1-$2-$3'** takes $1, $2, and $3 and puts dashes between them.  Click on **Run code snippet** and check it out.  Additionally, a _please_ would be much appreciated. -K

Comment: You should add that explanation to your answer, with less snark. You should start reading things like the poster has a positive attitude, otherwise you're doomed to an offended life on the internet ;) It's the internet. I don't have to say please to be nice.

Comment: Aside from that, nice explanation. Very thorough.

Comment: I just tried implementing this and it works!  Thank you so much :)  I really need to learn jQuery/JS better so I can start dealing with things like this easier.  I had a similar solution with a regex but couldn't figure out how to split the 3-3-4 digit pattern.  You guys are awesome!

Comment: If you change the regexp to this pattern: `/\D*(\d{3})\D*(\d{3})\D*(\d{4})\D*/`, it will match other formats like `(123) 456-7890` and `123.456.7890`

Answer (score 1):

```
function phoneMask() { 
    num = $(this).val().replace(/\D/g,''); 
    $(this).val(num.substring(0,3) + '-' + num.substring(3,6) + '-' + num.substring(6,10)); 
}
$('[type="tel"]').keyup(phonemask)
```

How it works:  take the phone number, get rid of any non-numeric characters.  Then, take the first 3 numbers, add a dash, take the next three, add a dash, and take the next four.

I changed the selector to `[type="tel"]` because you should be setting the input type to `tel` for phone numbers, and then this function will apply it to all phone number inputs.  But if that doesn't suit your needs, change it back to `#call_caller_phone`

Comment: Great solution that does not require plugin. Simple and elegant. In my case I made a small modification because my elements were added dynamically: $(document).on('keyup', '[type=tel], phoneMask);

Answer (score 1):

This will allow only numeric input in the text field (and '-'s) and only allow the 10 digits (plus 2 '-'s) for the US style phone numbers.  It inserts the dashes as the user types as well. Might be worth looking at compared to doing the whole thing at the end. But, there are good jquery libraries out there to handle input masks as well, [masked input plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/).

```js
$('#phone').keyup(function(ev) {
  var key = ev.which;
  if (key < 48 || key > 57 || key != 45) {
    ev.preventDefault();
  }

  if (this.value.length > 12) {
    this.value = this.value.slice(0, -1);
    return;
  }

  this.value = this.value.replace(/^(\d{3})(\d)/, '$1-$2')
    .replace(/^(\d{3}-\d{3})(\d)/, '$1-$2');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id='phone' />
```