# Need Help in Regex (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex

Before submitting the form, I am having values like (33) 3333-3333 and (333) 333-3333. I need to check these kind of values in regex before submitting the form.

If the value is in the above format, I have to remove the special characters, whitespace and have it as numbers alone: 3333333333

Please help me in writing a regex in javascript.

Comment: what exactly do you want to check? number format for phone numbers?

Comment: @VamshiAlladi-I want to check for phone numbers

Comment: I don't know about you, but I write my phone number as 01234 5678901.

Comment: Looks like it's duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760070/how-to-format-a-phone-number-with-jquery  or   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26412623/jquery-or-javascript-to-autoformat-phone-mask

Comment: @SudiptaMaiti if you read the question, Mark is specifically asking how to check that the value entered is a valid telephone number with a regular expression. He is **not** asking how to format a phone number as in the two questions you provided. Though, this question has been asked plenty of times, your evidence isn't valid.

Comment: Please note that this only verifies that the number conforms to your definition of a phone number format. It doesn't verify that the phone number even exists, or that it is the phone number of the person signing up. In this sense, you might want to ask yourself if it makes sense to perform this check, and risk annoying the user who (for example) thoughtfully includes the international dialling code.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="tel" />
```

Job done. [Specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.tel.html)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10578287)

Comment: @SHAZ I would consider the code sample, `<input type="tel" />` to be the "essential part of the answer" ;) The fact that the link is explicitly labelled "Specs", specifications, a form of reference... yeah, I think you reviewed a bit too fast XD

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you to use a regex like this:

```
/^\((\d{2,3})\) ?(\d{3,4})-(\d{4})$/
```

And using substitutions like `$1$2$3`

[[Regex Demo]](https://regex101.com/r/zX0qY9/2)

Answer (score -1):

Use this regex:-

```
 str.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')
```

Comment: -I have to remove the special characters and whitespaces too. Can you please help me on that

Comment: I updated the regex. Hope it will work for you.