# Number formatting

Tags: jquery, number-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to format a phone number with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760070/jquery-phone-number-format)

I want to format a number like this.

```
"XXX-XX-XXXX"
```

How can I make this?

Comment: this [link](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-numberformatter/) examine

Comment: `^(\d{3}-?\d{2}-?\d{4}|XXX-XX-XXXX)$` should do the trick.

Comment: I think people who vote to close a question with absolutely no comment as to why, are very dumb. This seems like a perfectly legitimate question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this great plugin for all your number formattings

http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/