# Format string as phone number in JavaScript/Lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

There is the following phone number string: '+79021234567'. How can I format this string as '+7 902 123-45-67'? I can do it manually with substring, but may be there is more elegant way? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a phone number with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760070/how-to-format-a-phone-number-with-jquery)

Comment: More elegant than what? You gave us no point of reference and there are lots and lots of ways to manipulate strings

Comment: Substring seems to be the way to go...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str.substring(start, end)` does seem to be the most applicable way, although it does not seem very elegant:

```
> str = '+79021234567'
> console.log([[str.substring(0, 2), str.substring(2, 5), str.substring(5, 8)].join(" "), str.substring(8, 10), str.substring(10)].join("-"));
+7 902 123-45-67
```