# How to format a phone number with jQuery including iOS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ios, windows

I'm currently displaying phone numbers like 2124771000. However, I need the number to be formatted in a more human-readable form, for example: (212)-477-1000. Here's my current HTML:

```
<p class="phone">2124771000</p>
```

I am using [How to format a phone number with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760070/how-to-format-a-phone-number-with-jquery)
 article and it works well in windows, but it's not working in iOS.

I want JavaScript that works in both platform as well as iOS.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need jquery (or js at all in fact) to do this. If the phone numbers are being inputted, then you can add a  HTML5 [`pattern`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp) to the input box to ensure users follow the suggested pattern as in the following example:.

```css
form {
  width:60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

input[type="tel"] {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 4px 8px;
}
input[type="tel"]:focus {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  background: #3b5998;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="alert('Submitted'); return false;">
  <h2>US Phone Number Validation</h2>
  <label for="phonenum">Phone Number (xxx-xxx-xxxx): </label>
  <input type="tel" id="phonenum" required pattern="\d{3}[\-]\d{3}[\-]\d{4}"/> 
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

There is an article displaying various types of phone patterns [here](http://html5pattern.com/Phones)