# Angular - Format a text field as phone number only if number is entered

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an input field that takes in an email or phone number. I want to apply UI mask only if phone number is entered but not when alphabets are entered. How can this be achieved?

Comment: What is a "UI mask"?

Comment: This post may help https://blog.imaginea.com/pipe-vs-filter-in-angular-js/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760070/how-to-format-a-phone-number-with-jquery - you may be able to do it with a helper function in plain old Javascript and Regex's. This might help for alphabetic chars only https://stackoverflow.com/a/25352300/495157

Comment: @HankScorpio - UI mask : https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-mask. if my input field is expected to receive only number input - this solution will be perfect http://angular-formly.com/#/example/integrations/ui-mask .